# Calculate the area enclosed by three curves $y = \ln x$, $y = \frac 8 x$, $y = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am really struggle in this Calculus 1 question. 
It asked me to calculate the area enclosed by $y = \ln x$, $y = \frac 8 x$, and $y = 1$. One big problem is I can't find the intersection between $lnx$ and $8/x$. Are there any better approaches for this? [image]

Comment: A good general rule of thumb is that when you can't easily find the intersection of two curves, it's not possible, in this the intersection point can't be found in terms of any known functions or constants. In this case, the trick to solve it is to integrate "wrt dy" So you set up an integral of the form x dy, where you get the x by "right-left"

Comment: Hint: As interchanging x and y wouldn't change the area, try doing that and see how the problem can be solved now.

Comment: BTW, at the intersection point, $x=\frac{x+8}{\ln x+1}$

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal I don't see what this helps. Won't we still need the $y$-coordinate of the intersection? Which is $W(8)$, which isn't much nicer than the $x$-coordinate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glancing at the plot, we expect the area is about $1\frac12$. Let $a$ denote the positive root of $\frac{8}{x}=\ln x$. The desired area is$$\begin{align}A&:=\int_e^a(\ln x-1)dx+\int_a^8\left(\frac8x-1\right)dx\\&=a\ln a-a+8\ln\frac8a-8+e\\&=e-a+8\ln\ln a.\end{align}$$By numerical methods, $a\approx4.982$ so $A\approx1.525$. We can write a closed form with e.g. $a=e^{W(8)}=\frac{1}{W(8)}$.

Answer (score 0):

I found the intersection point as 5. Using shift mode 7, for both lnx and 8/x, I compared the values starting from 2 till 8, since these are the extremes. I found x=5 to be the closest as lnx produced a value of 1.609 and 8/x gave 1.6.
I then integrated lnx from e to 5. Ans=-0.167
And 8/x from 5 till 8. Ans= 0.625
Adding them together, I got 0.458

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).